# Why did RecognitionListener stop working in JellyBean?

Tags: android, voice-recognition

For everyone using Android's [voice recognition API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/RecognizerIntent.html), there used to be a handy [RecognitionListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/RecognitionListener.html#onBufferReceived%28byte%5B%5D%29) you could register that would push various events to your callbacks. In particular, there was the following [`onBufferReceived(byte[])`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/RecognitionListener.html#onBufferReceived%28byte%5B%5D%29) method:

> `public abstract void onBufferReceived (byte[] buffer)`
>
> *Since: API Level 8* More sound has been received. The purpose of this
>   function is to allow giving feedback to the user regarding the
>   captured audio. There is no guarantee that this method will be called.
>
> **Parameters** `buffer`   a buffer containing a sequence of big-endian 16-bit
>   integers representing a single channel audio stream. The sample rate
>   is implementation dependent.

Although the method explicitly states that there is no *guarantee* it will be called, in ICS and prior it would effectively be called 100% of the time: regularly enough, at least, that by concatenating all the bytes received this way, you could reconstruct the entire audio stream and play it back.

For some reason, however, in the Jellybean SDK, **this magically stopped working**. There's no notice of deprecation and the code still compiles, but the `onBufferReceived` is now **never** called. Technically this isn't breaking their API (since it says there's "no guarantee" the method will be called), but clearly this is a breaking change for a lot of things that depended on this behaviour.

Does anybody know why this functionality was disabled, and if there's a way to replicate its behaviour on Jellybean?

**Clarification**: I realize that the whole `RecognizerIntent` thing is an interface with multiple implementations (including some available on the Play Store), and that they can each choose what to do with `RecognitionListener`. I am specifically referring to the default Google implementation that the vast majority of Jellybean phones use.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Google does not call this method their Jelly Bean speech app (QuickSearchBox). Its simply not in the code. Unless there is an official comment from a Google Engineer I cannot give a definite answer "why" they did this. I did search the developer forums but did not see any commentary about this decision.

The ics default for speech recognition comes from Google's VoiceSearch.apk. You can decompile this apk and see and find see there is an Activity to handle an intent of action *android.speech.action.RECOGNIZE_SPEECH*. In this apk I searched for "onBufferReceived" and found a reference to it in *com.google.android.voicesearch.GoogleRecognitionService$RecognitionCallback*.

With Jelly Bean, Google renamed VoiceSearch.apk to QuickSearch.apk and made a lot of new additions to the app (ex. offline dictation). You would expect to still find an onBufferReceived call, but for some reason it is completely gone.

Comment: Thanks for the in-depth analysis confirming that the issue is universal on Jellybean :) I guess the only way it can get more definitive is if we get a Google engineer to explain _why_ this happened. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I too was using the onBufferReceived method and was disappointed that the (non-guaranteed) call to the method was dropped in Jelly Bean. Well, if we can't grab the audio with onBufferReceived(), maybe there is a possibility of running an AudioRecord simultaneously with voice recognition. Anyone tried this?  If not, I'll give it a whirl and report back.

Comment: I doubt it's possible, but I'd love to hear your results.

Comment: Well, I gave it a good try, but it looks like running an AudioRecord and SpeechRecognizer at the same time won't work.  Only one of them can get access to the microphone.  So, back to to needing onBufferReceived() to work....  come on Google, make it so!

Answer (score 0):

I ran in to the same problem. The reason why I didn't just accept that "this does not work" was because Google Nows "note-to-self" record the audio and sends it to you. What I found out in logcat while running the "note-to-self"-operation was:

```
02-20 14:04:59.664: I/AudioService(525):  AudioFocus  requestAudioFocus() from android.media.AudioManager@42439ca8com.google.android.voicesearch.audio.ByteArrayPlayer$1@424cca50

02-20 14:04:59.754: I/AbstractCardController.SelfNoteController(8675): #attach
02-20 14:05:01.006: I/AudioService(525):  AudioFocus  abandonAudioFocus() from android.media.AudioManager@42439ca8com.google.android.voicesearch.audio.ByteArrayPlayer$1@424cca50

02-20 14:05:05.791: I/ActivityManager(525): START u0 {act=com.google.android.gm.action.AUTO_SEND typ=text/plain cmp=com.google.android.gm/.AutoSendActivity (has extras)} from pid 8675
02-20 14:05:05.821: I/AbstractCardView.SelfNoteCard(8675): #onViewDetachedFromWindow
```

This makes me belive that google disposes the audioFocus from google now (the regonizerIntent), and that they use an audio recorder or something similar when the Note-to-self-tag appears in onPartialResults. I can not confirm this, has anyone else made tries to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

I have a service that is implementing RecognitionListener and I also override onBufferReceived(byte[]) method. I was investigating  why the speech recognition is much slower to call onResults() on <=ICS . The only difference I could find was that onBufferReceived is called on phones <= ICS. On JellyBean the onBufferReceived() is never called and onResults() is called significantly faster and I'm thinking its because of the overhead to call onBufferReceived every second or millisecond. Maybe thats why they did away with  onBufferReceived()?