# RecognitionListener in JellyBean Freezes if not spoken to immediately

Tags: android, speech-recognition, android-4.2-jelly-bean

A speech-recognition based app I am working on works well on all versions of Android starting from API 8 (Android 2.2).

But on a Nexus S 4G (Android 4.1.1), RecognitionListener will simply **halt for about 1 minute**, then issue an ERROR_SERVER via its [onError()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/RecognitionListener.html#onError%28int%29) callback.

If spoken to within **1-2** seconds (of that [onReadyForSpeech](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/RecognitionListener.html#onReadyForSpeech%28android.os.Bundle%29) bleep), it will behave properly as expected.

What changed in JellyBean that could explain this behavior?

More importantly, is there a way to make it behave like in the older versions of Android?
(i.e. keep listening, then issue ERROR_SPEECH_TIMEOUT if not spoken to within the default **10 seconds**)

Comment: This SNAFU of breaking backward compatibility sounds familiar... I recently came across a similar post, [with no answer in sight](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13670378/576267). Maybe it's related to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11839541/576267)? Good luck!

Comment: Yes, this issue has been introduced in Jellybean.  You should keep an eye on the linked post, as it has a 100 point bounty on it.

Comment: See my work around including muting the beep sound at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14940657/android-speech-recognition-as-a-service-on-android-4-1-4-2/14950616#14950616

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using the solution suggested by [@scriptocalypse](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14223908/679180)

Thank you @scriptocalypse!

(I haven't had the chance to try the solution suggested by [@HoanNguyen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14950616/679180) because it implements a service which is beyond the scope of my tiny app, but it looks promising. Thank you @HoanNguyen, too.)

Answer (score -2):

There is a [similar post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11196052/speechrecognizer-not-hearing-after-first-result) that offers the suggestion of simply listening again up on receiving ERROR_TIMEOUT_SPEECH result.