# Voice speech recognition android remove google screen and microphone button

Tags: android, speech-recognition

I'm using voice speech recognition from Android API.

I followed successfully this tutorial:
http://code4reference.com/2012/07/tutorial-android-voice-recognition/#comment-335

But I've an unsolved question.

How cain I remove the screen that appear when calling RecognizerIntent??

I'm talking about removing google and microphone button that advice that I'm using speech recognition.

I need to remove this small screen because I need to do other things on screen while that is recognizeing my voice.

Comment: Hi. Really thanks for the quick response.
Now I'm dealing with something bigger, but is about the same area.
If you want to help me, this is the post:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15917315/speech-recognition-on-unity-game-engine

Answer (score 5):

You need to write a service class that call `createSpeechRecognizer`. You can get an idea of how to do it in my answer at [Android Speech Recognition as a service on Android 4.1 & 4.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14940657/android-speech-recognition-as-a-service-on-android-4-1-4-2/14950616#14950616)

Comment: Hi. Really thanks for the quick response.
Now I'm dealing with something bigger, but is about the same area.
If you want to help me, this is the post:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15917315/speech-recognition-on-unity-game-engine

Comment: Well, I have not develop game, so I have no idea if you can use Google speech recognition in Unity Engine.

Answer (score 1):

You'd need to work at a lower level than this example.  What this example does is launch an app that does voice recognition for you and sends you the results.  That app is drawing the UI, and you can't stop it.  What you'd need to do is write an app against the service that actually does the voice recognition (basicly, exactly what that intent is doing).  You can probably find an example of this in the Android keyboard code, as they provide a custom UI against Google voice.

Comment: Hi. Really thanks for the quick response.
Now I'm dealing with something bigger, but is about the same area.
If you want to help me, this is the post:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15917315/speech-recognition-on-unity-game-engine

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this. The screen is not displayed by your app, but is displayed by the voice recognition API instead, and you cannot control it.

In any case, that screen is a standard for voice recognition on the device, and users are familiar with it. It would be something of an anti pattern to remove it and conduct voice recognition. With the screen there, users will know that voice recognition is active, and that the microphone is picking up sound as it provides that feedback.

Comment: Hi. Really thanks for the quick response.
Now I'm dealing with something bigger, but is about the same area.
If you want to help me, this is the post:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15917315/speech-recognition-on-unity-game-engine

Answer (score 0):

Use `SpeechRecognizer`. The Intent mechanism is similar.

For convienience use the `recognizeDirectly` method in this [helper class](https://github.com/gast-lib/gast-lib/blob/master/library/src/root/gast/speech/SpeechRecognizingActivity.java)