# Speech Recognition on Unity Game Engine

Tags: android, ios, unity-game-engine, speech-recognition

I've succesfully achieved the goal of developing an app on android that use speech recognition from Google API.

But the fact is that I must use a real Game Engine because my app is going to be crossplatform and with a very rich User Interfacea and gestures.

I'm thinking on using Unity Game Engine and I'm going to deploy my app to iOS and Android platforms.

So... searching on web... I figured out that I can't use Google Speech Recognition API on Unity Game Engine becuase its belong to Google... Is that true?

Could you please give me an advice on how to implement this?

First option:
Implement a third part library or Unity Speech Recognition API. Wich ones?

Second option (It's possible??):
Modularize the package that convert speech to text, and call it via dynamic reflection.
On Android deploy, use a Google API.
On iOS deploy, use a iOS API (Unkown too).

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can use pocketsphinx it should be available on android and iOS
http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/ Look at OpenEar for iOS which is based on PocketSphinx as well.

Comment: check this plugin: https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/73036 . It supports iOS and Android.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend looking at CMU Sphinx. http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0):

You can use google's speech recognition with Unity- on Android.  On iOS you need to use something else.  Unfortunately, as of 6 months ago when I checked iOS didn't have built in speech recognition APIs.  So you'll need to try and find a 3rd party library to do it.

Answer (score 0):

in the new beta version (5.4), Unity added DictationRecognizer wich is a class that provide speech recognition from microsoft. The accuracy is really good.