# Keep speech on android

Tags: android, speech

So I'm building an application on my phone that will let it do commands based on what I say but the problem is that you always will have to startup the application or press A button in the application.

So is there a way it will keep listening or maybe if I say a command word it will startup automaticly without me having to do something?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a service that listens for speech. A service code can be found at [Android Speech Recognition as a service on Android 4.1 & 4.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14940657/android-speech-recognition-as-a-service-on-android-4-1-4-2/14950616#14950616)