# Voice Search/SpeechRecognizer crashes on rapid start/stop listening

Tags: android, speech-recognition

I have an app that uses SpeechRecognizer (in onCreate function):

```
mIntent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
mIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_CALLING_PACKAGE, this.getPackageName());
mRecognizer = SpeechRecognizer.createSpeechRecognizer(this);
mRecognizer.setRecognitionListener(this);
```

I have a single button that starts and stops the speech recognition (in onClick):

```
if (view.getId() == R.id.btnSpeak) {
    if (mIsRecording) {
        mRecognizer.stopListening();
        mBtnSpeak.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.mic);
        mIsCanceled = true;

    } else {
        mRecognizer.startListening(mIntent);
        mBtnSpeak.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.mic_green);
    }

    mIsRecording = !mIsRecording;
}
```

The problem is when I rapidly tap the button as soon as the activity starts, a force close notification appears with this error log:

```
05-28 11:35:19.460: E/AndroidRuntime(9288): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-28 11:35:19.460: E/AndroidRuntime(9288): java.lang.NullPointerException
05-28 11:35:19.460: E/AndroidRuntime(9288):     at com.google.android.voicesearch.speechservice.MicrophoneManagerImpl.stopListening(MicrophoneManagerImpl.java:195)
05-28 11:35:19.460: E/AndroidRuntime(9288):     at com.google.android.voicesearch.speechservice.RecognitionControllerImpl.onStopListening(RecognitionControllerImpl.java:280)
05-28 11:35:19.460: E/AndroidRuntime(9288):     at com.google.android.voicesearch.GoogleRecognitionService.onStopListening(GoogleRecognitionService.java:58)
05-28 11:35:19.460: E/AndroidRuntime(9288):     at android.speech.RecognitionService.dispatchStopListening(RecognitionService.java:118)
05-28 11:35:19.460: E/AndroidRuntime(9288):     at android.speech.RecognitionService.access$100(RecognitionService.java:36)
05-28 11:35:19.460: E/AndroidRuntime(9288):     at android.speech.RecognitionService$1.handleMessage(RecognitionService.java:82)
05-28 11:35:19.460: E/AndroidRuntime(9288):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-28 11:35:19.460: E/AndroidRuntime(9288):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
05-28 11:35:19.460: E/AndroidRuntime(9288):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3746)
05-28 11:35:19.460: E/AndroidRuntime(9288):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-28 11:35:19.460: E/AndroidRuntime(9288):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
05-28 11:35:19.460: E/AndroidRuntime(9288):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:895)
05-28 11:35:19.460: E/AndroidRuntime(9288):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:653)
05-28 11:35:19.460: E/AndroidRuntime(9288):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-28 11:35:19.460: E/AndroidRuntime(9288): [Blue Error Handler] Make Debugging Report file for main
05-28 11:35:19.460: E/AndroidRuntime(9288): java.lang.NullPointerException
05-28 11:35:19.460: E/AndroidRuntime(9288):     at com.google.android.voicesearch.speechservice.MicrophoneManagerImpl.stopListening(MicrophoneManagerImpl.java:195)
05-28 11:35:19.460: E/AndroidRuntime(9288):     at com.google.android.voicesearch.speechservice.RecognitionControllerImpl.onStopListening(RecognitionControllerImpl.java:280)
05-28 11:35:19.460: E/AndroidRuntime(9288):     at com.google.android.voicesearch.GoogleRecognitionService.onStopListening(GoogleRecognitionService.java:58)
05-28 11:35:19.460: E/AndroidRuntime(9288):     at android.speech.RecognitionService.dispatchStopListening(RecognitionService.java:118)
05-28 11:35:19.460: E/AndroidRuntime(9288):     at android.speech.RecognitionService.access$100(RecognitionService.java:36)
05-28 11:35:19.460: E/AndroidRuntime(9288):     at android.speech.RecognitionService$1.handleMessage(RecognitionService.java:82)
05-28 11:35:19.460: E/AndroidRuntime(9288):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-28 11:35:19.460: E/AndroidRuntime(9288):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
05-28 11:35:19.460: E/AndroidRuntime(9288):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3746)
05-28 11:35:19.460: E/AndroidRuntime(9288):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-28 11:35:19.460: E/AndroidRuntime(9288):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
05-28 11:35:19.460: E/AndroidRuntime(9288):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:895)
05-28 11:35:19.460: E/AndroidRuntime(9288):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:653)
05-28 11:35:19.460: E/AndroidRuntime(9288):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

It does not crash the application but I would like to prevent this from happening.  From what I understand from the logs, my code called stoplistening before the speech recognizer is ready.  Is there a way to check if its ok to stopListening/startListening?

Additionally, the bug only occurs if I rapidly tap it as soon as the activity starts.  Otherwise, speechrecognizer just calls onError and I can update my button from there.  I'm contemplating on adding a delay to give speechrecognizer sometime to process thing through but it feels clunky.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `mRecognizer.stopListening();` you should call `mRecognizer.cancel();`
If the OS is JB you have to implement a countdown timer see [Android Speech Recognition as a service on Android 4.1 & 4.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14940657/android-speech-recognition-as-a-service-on-android-4-1-4-2/14950616#14950616)

Answer (score 1):

You can't quite replace stop with cancel and say it solves the rapid stop problem because cancel isn't the same -

`cancel` will stop the recognizer and not show any results.
`stopListening` will stop the recording and trigger the `onResults` listener callback with the transcription of the recording so far.

On my phone (OS 4.4.2) - I found calling `stopListening` before the `onReadyForSpeech` happened will cause the recognizer to become stuck!  No `onResults` or `onError` is called and attempting to start it again causes a BUSY error.

The solution - set mIsRecording to true only on `onReadyForSpeech`

When you want to stop the recognizer call `stopListening` only if the flag is true. If its false then call `cancel` instead and trigger the end event manually.