# How to disable or mute beep of android VoiceRecognizer?

Tags: android, voice-recognition

I am working on application in which I have implemented searching with VoiceRecognizer but I want to disable/mute beep.

If it is possible then please give best solution.

Comment: mAudioManager.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_SYSTEM, true), but you probably want to check more detailed answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18650072/android-speech-speech-recognition-repeated-calling-of-speechrecognizer-startlis