# Continuous speech recognition stops above 4.2 OS version

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, speech-recognition, android-4.4-kitkat

I have implemented [Android Speech Recognition as a service on Android 4.1 & 4.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14940657/android-speech-recognition-as-a-service-on-android-4-1-4-2) recognition solution in my application.
Everything is fine until Android 4.2 OS version, but above the recognition doesn't work. I tested my solution on Kitkat and Lollipop.
The service starts run 2-3 times(i can see the log in the handler), then stops without any error. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20257122/2743818) they mentioned about a similar problem, but no solution.

I refreshed Google Play Services to 7.5, but not that is the source of the problem.
Any suggestion is appreciated!

Update:
The suggested solution, to observe if the service runs, just a partial solution, i can restart listen the recognizer with startListening method, but it's not listening at all. I'm considering to use other recognition service, like sphinx. It is so embarrasing, when OS version changes and your app will be wrecked... 
I'm aware about the fact, this API is not intended to be used for continuous recognition - as mentioned in documentation.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android Speech Speech Recognition: Repeated Calling of SpeechRecognizer.startListening() fails on JB 4.1.2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18650072/android-speech-speech-recognition-repeated-calling-of-speechrecognizer-startlis)

Comment: There is no need to post the question again, you can just upvote/add bounty to the original question.