# Making the Phone Constantly Listen for Voice Input

Tags: android, speech-recognition

I am creating a personal assistant application and I want it to turn on its voice recognition system (e.g. google voice keyboard) whenever a certain set of words is spoken, when the application is visible on the device's screen. Very much like the already-existent feature of the samsung galaxy s3, with which you can say "unlock" if the phone is in lock state and the phone will unlock.

I don't know if voice recognition is an option for this(e.g. keep the mic on and start speech to text when the mic detects sound; therefore when the user says the keyword, the device unlocks) but I believe it should be possible. Worst case scenario I can see it being possible by matching the user's voice with existent audio files - although it wouldn't be as accurate as speech to text. Therefore STT is definitely my preference.

So my question is :

1) Is it possible to make the phone CONSTANTLY(even if the application is not displayed, root access is not an issue) listen for voice recognition and execute a line of code whenever a certain set of words is spoken? If so, how? Keep in mind that battery resources are irrelevant in my application.

Comment: it is possible with root, how: search it :)

Comment: Do you mind giving me some clues how? Edit: will look it up now

Comment: a lot of undocumented stuff, it is booooring, but if you need spy app, that is the way to go, you can find a few examples too

Comment: I'm not trying to create a spy app, I actually need voice recognition to run in the background.

Comment: AI on android... even for a simple crypto is slow the android's CPU... take a look here: http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/5-free-siri-alternatives-for-android-which-is-the-best/

Answer (score 3):

You have to write a "speech recognizer" service and in that service acquire a wakelock. For a service code you can find at [Android Speech Recognition as a service on Android 4.1 & 4.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14940657/android-speech-recognition-as-a-service-on-android-4-1-4-2/14950616#14950616)

Comment: How do u get a wake lock in it

Comment: Okay, thanks so much for your response. I saw the code in that linked answer, but is there any way to just listen for one keyword? I know I would need certain code in a service, with a wake lock, but how would I listen for a keyword? Again, thanks so much!

Comment: Then you better use Sphinx or just ignore everything except for that keyword. That is onResult check if the keyword was spoken. By using Sphinx you can completely get rid of the annoying beep which is impossible to get rid using Google speech recognizer.