# google's voice recognition + media recorder

Tags: android, voice-recognition

I need some opinions or advice if whether or not if it's possible. I have an app that uses the voice recognition api and the media recorder. The gist of the app is when the user says "note", it will record the voice message till the user says "finish". After that, the app saves the voice message into the phone.

I currently have a pop up box with buttons (record, save, stop, done) where the user manually presses the buttons to record their voice message. I'm looking into fully transform the app where the user has total voice control. So basically, the more hands free it is, the better.

I looked into continuous voice recognition from here: [Android Speech Recognition as a service on Android 4.1 & 4.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14940657/android-speech-recognition-as-a-service-on-android-4-1-4-2/14950616#14950616) but not entirely sure if it's a good solution considering the user's voice recording time can vary. (I read that it sucks the battery life really bad using continuous)

I researched and found that it's not possible with Google's voice recognition since it uses the internet to send the words so google's server can process it.

I'm a bit stump, would be great if I can get some advice or opinions.

Answer (score 0):

user1704756, Google Speech Recognition can not help you when offline. I think your demand is similar to what google glass do as below.

[image: wakeup model]

> "OK, Google Glass." is the wakeup word that is being detected continuously. When wakeup word be detected, the content will be send to deal with ASR.

In your project, "note" & "finish" is your wakeup word which can promot when to start and stop. Some wakeup engine offers the voice data callback, you can get the data that has been remove wakeup word data from here. Above all,it is hard to realize.

As I know, wakeup need to continuously record voice and compute, so, it is unfriendly to the battery. To avoid overcoming the disadvantage , Moto X phone use extra low power consumption chip to do this.

May [it](http://open.aispeech.com/sdk/AISpeech-SDK-for-Android-1.4.1-20130521.zip) can help you.