# Android, Continuous Voice Recogntion and error IO Exception

Tags: java, android

I have a trouble with VR continuous. In my code there are a fragment that implement VR.

It works but sometime I saw that without any apparent reason it stops. No error, NO crash, I'm able to restart by taping on button two time.

Log doesn't help, this is what I got byt LogCat

```
08-27 23:46:00.708 I/AudioService(433):  AudioFocus  requestAudioFocus() from android.media.AudioManager@422819d8com.google.android.voicesearch.audio.AudioRouterImpl$1@4229e1a8
08-27 23:46:00.755 I/VS.G3EngineManager(15890): create_rm: m=ENDPOINTER_DICTATION,l=en-US
08-27 23:46:00.770 I/VS.G3EngineManager(15890): Brought up new g3 instance :/system/usr/srec/en-US/endpointer_dictation.config for: en-USin: 13 ms
08-27 23:46:00.848 W/Sidekick_LocationOracleImpl(15890): Best location was null
08-27 23:46:00.856 W/Sidekick_LocationOracleImpl(15890): Best location was null
08-27 23:46:01.505 I/ActivityManager(433): Start proc com.devexpert.weather for broadcast com.devexpert.weather/.view.WidgetWeather2x1: pid=16138 uid=10071 gids={50071, 3003, 1015, 1028}
08-27 23:46:01.911 W/RecognitionDispatcher(15890): Could not stop engine 3
08-27 23:46:06.356 I/MicrophoneInputStream(15890): mic_close
08-27 23:46:06.388 I/AudioService(433):  AudioFocus  abandonAudioFocus() from android.media.AudioManager@422819d8com.google.android.voicesearch.audio.AudioRouterImpl$1@4229e1a8 
08-27 23:46:06.411 I/decoder (15890): INFO: recognition time wall: 5.61636 sec user: 1.49219 sec sys: 0.234375 sec 
08-27 23:46:06.544 I/GoogleRecognitionServiceImpl(15890): #startListening [it-IT]
08-27 23:46:06.552 I/AudioService(433):  AudioFocus  requestAudioFocus() from android.media.AudioManager@422819d8com.google.android.voicesearch.audio.AudioRouterImpl$1@4229e1a8
08-27 23:46:06.552 I/VS.G3EngineManager(15890): create_rm: m=ENDPOINTER_DICTATION,l=en-US
08-27 23:46:06.575 I/VS.G3EngineManager(15890): Brought up new g3 instance :/system/usr/srec/en-US/endpointer_dictation.config for: en-USin: 25 ms
08-27 23:46:06.598 W/Sidekick_LocationOracleImpl(15890): Best location was null
08-27 23:46:06.606 W/Sidekick_LocationOracleImpl(15890): Best location was null
08-27 23:46:07.661 W/RecognitionDispatcher(15890): Could not stop engine 3
08-27 23:46:11.231 I/MicrophoneInputStream(15890): mic_close
08-27 23:46:11.263 I/AudioService(433):  AudioFocus  abandonAudioFocus() from android.media.AudioManager@422819d8com.google.android.voicesearch.audio.AudioRouterImpl$1@4229e1a8
08-27 23:46:11.278 I/decoder (15890): INFO: recognition time wall: 4.67749 sec user: 1.21875 sec sys: 0.21875 sec 
08-27 23:46:11.395 I/GoogleRecognitionServiceImpl(15890): #startListening [it-IT]
08-27 23:46:11.411 I/AudioService(433):  AudioFocus  requestAudioFocus() from android.media.AudioManager@422819d8com.google.android.voicesearch.audio.AudioRouterImpl$1@4229e1a8
08-27 23:46:11.419 I/VS.G3EngineManager(15890): create_rm: m=ENDPOINTER_DICTATION,l=en-US
08-27 23:46:11.450 I/VS.G3EngineManager(15890): Brought up new g3 instance :/system/usr/srec/en-US/endpointer_dictation.config for: en-USin: 28 ms
08-27 23:46:11.450 W/Search.ConcurrentUtils(15890): Executor queue length is now 2. Perhaps some tasks are too long, or the pool is too small. [GrecoExecutor-1]
08-27 23:46:11.450 I/AudioService(433):  AudioFocus  abandonAudioFocus() from android.media.AudioManager@422819d8com.google.android.voicesearch.audio.AudioRouterImpl$1@4229e1a8
08-27 23:46:11.458 W/Sidekick_LocationOracleImpl(15890): Best location was null
08-27 23:46:11.458 W/Sidekick_LocationOracleImpl(15890): Best location was null
08-27 23:46:11.489 W/PairHttpConnection(15890): [Upload] Connection error
08-27 23:46:11.489 W/PairHttpConnection(15890): java.io.IOException: Timed out / error during connect
08-27 23:46:11.489 W/PairHttpConnection(15890):     at com.google.android.speech.network.PairHttpConnection.connect(PairHttpConnection.java:135)
08-27 23:46:11.489 W/PairHttpConnection(15890):     at com.google.android.speech.network.NetworkRecognitionRunner.runNetworkLoop(NetworkRecognitionRunner.java:219)
08-27 23:46:11.489 W/PairHttpConnection(15890):     at com.google.android.speech.network.NetworkRecognitionRunner.access$000(NetworkRecognitionRunner.java:54)
08-27 23:46:11.489 W/PairHttpConnection(15890):     at com.google.android.speech.network.NetworkRecognitionRunner$1.run(NetworkRecognitionRunner.java:73)
08-27 23:46:11.489 W/PairHttpConnection(15890):     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:390)
08-27 23:46:11.489 W/PairHttpConnection(15890):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
08-27 23:46:11.489 W/PairHttpConnection(15890):     at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:153)
08-27 23:46:11.489 W/PairHttpConnection(15890):     at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:267)
 08-27 23:46:11.489 W/PairHttpConnection(15890):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
08-27 23:46:11.489 W/PairHttpConnection(15890):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
08-27 23:46:11.489 W/PairHttpConnection(15890):     at com.google.android.searchcommon.util.ConcurrentUtils$1$1.run(ConcurrentUtils.java:90)
```

as you can see, there are 3 start of VR, last cycle it stops due to IOEXCEPTION

we got the source code from this github https://github.com/fcrisciani/android-speech-recognition/tree/master/VoiceRecognition/src/com/speech/fcrisciani/voicerecognition

Answer (score 0):

You are possibly dealing with a number of bugs here. The first one you need to catch has been [outstanding on the AOSP bug tracker for nearly a year](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=37883).

I posted on the [Google Product Forum about it here](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/mobile/PZMX9vmPPhQ/wswW28QZa8UJ) too, but no response. If you are reading this and would like these issues to be resolved, please do star the AOSP issue and comment on the Product Forum post to get it noticed!

To work around this issue, you'll need an implementation [such as the one demonstrated here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14950616/1256219).

Your particular bug was posted on the [AOSP bug tracker here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=55920), but closed as it was to do with Google Voice Search. Someone posted [regarding the bug on the Product Forum here](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/mobile/YjYPaq2eQKU/QGieOQb_c58J), but it was closed due to inactivity.

It's a joke that you cannot get Google to do anything about these things. I'd like to continue to rant, but best not....