# Android Offline Speech Recognition shows only one result?

Tags: android, speech-recognition, offline

I've set a speech recognition service as shown in this post [Android Speech Recognition as a service on Android 4.1 & 4.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14940657/android-speech-recognition-as-a-service-on-android-4-1-4-2/14950616#14950616) and when I use the offline recognition (putting the phone in plane mode) it only shows me 1 result in the onResults() while in online mode I always get more than 5 results.

I use this Intent :

```
mSpeechRecognizerIntent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
    mSpeechRecognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
                                     RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
    mSpeechRecognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_CALLING_PACKAGE,
                                     this.getPackageName());
    mSpeechRecognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, "fr-FR");
    mSpeechRecognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_MAX_RESULTS, 10);
```

I switched to english and it did the same. I also tried Web search instead of Free form.

I would like to know if there is some magic code to make it work or if it's just impossible to combine multiple results with offline recognition.

Thank you in advance