# Android Speech Recognition returning only one result offline

Tags: android, speech-recognition

I'm trying to use Android's speech recognition API offline, exactly like this question [Android Offline Speech Recognition shows only one result?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19403974/android-offline-speech-recognition-shows-only-one-result). I'm also getting five results when online and only one result offline, and would like to get five(ish) results in either case. Is this simply a limitation of Android's built-in speech recognition engine, or is there some hidden setting that can be changed to force more than one result?

Here's my Intent setup:

```
        Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_MAX_RESULTS,5);          
        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM); //< have tried both FREE_FORM and WEB_SEARCH
        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_CALLING_PACKAGE, getPackageName());
        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PARTIAL_RESULTS, true);
        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, "en-US");
        mRecognizer.startListening(intent);
```

And my onResults():

```
    @Override
    public void onResults(Bundle results) {

         // data.size() is 1, if running offline and generally 5, if online
         ArrayList<String> data = results.getStringArrayList(SpeechRecognizer.RESULTS_RECOGNITION); 
         //...
    }
```

I'm running Android 4.4.2.

Comment: Why do you ask exactly the same question as already exists?

Comment: Because that question doesn't have an answer.

Comment: You could just upvote the original question

Comment: I don't have the reputation to up-vote, so I asked the same question. The other question was asked a year ago, and it doesn't even have any comments.

Comment: I have yet to find any evidence that this behavior is not simply a limitation of the Android speech recognition API. I switched recognition engines to CMU Sphinx (http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/). It's not as simple to use, but it's not too bad. CMU Sphinx is very configurable, and, after a little acoustic model adaptation, I was eventually able to get better recognition results for my simple command-and-control app with CMU Sphinx than I had with the Android API.

Answer (score 0):

try to set MAX_RESULTS to 5,10,20 or whatever to see if it helps.