# Google Voice Typing on Activity

Tags: android, voice-recognition, voice, speech-to-text, ime

This is [Google Voice Typing](http://img.wonderhowto.com/img/03/68/63509153521251/0/type-more-accurately-efficiently-your-samsung-galaxy-s3-with-wordwaves-intelligent-keyboard.w654.jpg) I would like to implement it on a activity (not [IME](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/12/add-voice-typing-to-your-ime.html)), because it offers continous speech recognition.

I ve seen that some people ([like those guys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14940657/android-speech-recognition-as-a-service-on-android-4-1-4-2)) create a service which contains a speech recognition loop. I would like to avoid that, and use Google Voice Typing and get partial results.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [CMUSphinx](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutorialandroid), if your main goal is to recognize speech continuously. To achieve this using google speech recognition api, you might have to resort to continuous speech recognition which takes too much resources and drains the device battery.

On the other hand, Pocketsphinx works really great. It's fast enough to spot a key phrase and recognize voice commands behind the lock screen without users touching their device. And it does all this offline.
 You can try the [demo](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cmusphinx/files/pocketsphinx/5prealpha/pocketsphinx-android-demo-5prealpha.tar.gz/download).