# Android add pause RecognizerIntent for speech to text

Tags: android, delay, speech-recognition, voice-recognition, speech-to-text

I have implemented Speech to Text using RecognizerIntent and its working perfectly.

But I need to modify the working of it and want to add pause time while user is speaking, as practically user might stop for a while and then speak again, so I want the voice search to stay for few seconds for example 5 seconds if no voice heard then only it stops and process the speech.

I have tried using services buts its not working as desired. Prefer code examples.

[Implement something similar when I turn on Speech to Text key on Xperia Z3 keyboard, it accepts speech till user taps pause]

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android Speech Recognition as a service on Android 4.1 & 4.2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14940657/android-speech-recognition-as-a-service-on-android-4-1-4-2)

Answer (score 0):

[full duplex example](https://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/demos/speech.html) provides your needed feature ( handle pause inline )

This is diff implementation from RecognizerIntent and operates on a more complicated setup for handling mic's audio stream and for handling network connections for processing streams ( audio/UP , text/DOWN ).

So, if you want to use streaming AND continuously recognized speech that goes on until you signal the end of INPUT ( like click event on the mic icon in example ) it can be alot more involved.

[background](http://mikepultz.com/2013/07/google-speech-api-full-duplex-php-version)

[google API sample](http://pastebin.com/yYKJC9uv)

[IBM API sample](http://pastebin.com/heirDXui)

They are complicated. Either can be implemented on a good , android , httpclient.