# background service for voice command

Tags: android, android-service, speech-recognition

I need to use a background service to launch my application with voice command even when the screen is locked. For example when I say "start" the screen will be unlocked and the application launches automatically,  I tried to make this code  work https://github.com/gast-lib/gast-lib/blob/master/library/src/root/gast/speech/activation/SpeechActivationService.java
  but I don't know how to use that  and how to do the service with the activity .

Answer (score 0):

I'll recommend using [CMUSphinx](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/RecognizerIntent.html) to recognize speech continuously. To achieve continuous speech recognition using google speech recognition api, you might have to resort to a loop in a background service which will take too much resources and drains the device battery.

On the other hand, Pocketsphinx works really great. It's fast enough to spot a key phrase and recognize voice commands behind the lock screen without users touching their device. And it does all this offline. You can try the [demo](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cmusphinx/files/pocketsphinx/5prealpha/pocketsphinx-android-demo-5prealpha.tar.gz/download).

If you really want to use google's api as I've demonstrated above, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14940657/android-speech-recognition-as-a-service-on-android-4-1-4-2)

Comment: so how can i make the battery don't lose resources ?

Comment: by decreasing the number of times you automatically listen for speech