# Continuous Speech Recognition Android - Without Gaps

Tags: android, speech-recognition, speech, recognizer-intent

I have an activity that implements `RecognitionListener`. To make it continuous, every time `onEndOfSpeech()` I start the listener again:

```
speech.startListening(recognizerIntent);
```

But, it takes some time (around half a second) till it starts, so there is this half a second gap, where nothing is listening. Therefore, I miss words that were spoken in that time difference.

On the other hand, when I use Google's Voice input, to dictate messages instead of the keyboard - this time gap does not exist. Meaning - there is a solution.

What is it?

Thanks

Comment: Do you got success in this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try looking at a couple other api's....

[speech demo](https://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/demos/speech.html) : has source [here](https://github.com/scheib/chromium/blob/master/content/browser/speech/google_streaming_remote_engine.cc) and is discussed [here](http://mikepultz.com/2013/07/google-speech-api-full-duplex-php-version/) and operated on CLI [here](http://pastebin.com/juZcNidK)

you could use the full duplex google api ( its rate capped at 50 per day )

Or if you like that general idea check ibm's watson discussed [here](https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/175476/watson-speech-to-text-response-not-continuous.html)

IMO - its more complex but not capped .

Comment: http streaming to 3rd party services seems the only solution at this point.

Answer (score 5):

I'll recommend using [CMUSphinx](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutorialandroid) to recognize speech continuously. To achieve continuous speech recognition using google speech recognition api, you might have to resort to a loop in a background service which will take too much resources and drains the device battery.

On the other hand, Pocketsphinx works really great. It's fast enough to spot a key phrase and recognize voice commands behind the lock screen without users touching their device. And it does all this offline. You can try the [demo](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cmusphinx/files/pocketsphinx/5prealpha/pocketsphinx-android-demo-5prealpha.tar.gz/download).

If you really want to use google's api, [see this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14940657/android-speech-recognition-as-a-service-on-android-4-1-4-2)

Comment: Thanks, though Pocketsphinx does not work well for natural - speech dictation (it works great for a limited grammar - great for commands), and doesn't the solution in the link to google's api result in the same problem as I posted?

Comment: How do I download pocketsphinx

Comment: @RuchirBaronia  Download from the official site http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/

Comment: How can I implement it in a service? Thanks!

Comment: do you have example code for android because i useing this and i add hot words like ok light but it still tregir on others words

Answer (score 2):

There are options like:

```
intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_SPEECH_INPUT_COMPLETE_SILENCE_LENGTH_MILLIS, 2000); // value to wait
```

or

```
intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_SPEECH_INPUT_POSSIBLY_COMPLETE_SILENCE_LENGTH_MILLIS, 2000);
```

These ceased to work on Jelly Bean and above, but work on ICS and below - not sure if intended or a bug!