# Android voice commands through notifications

Tags: java, android

Is it possible to send voice commands to an application via background service/ notification?

I know it works when the application is in foreground; I need to use a Bluetooth headset and send commands to an application while this runs in the background as a service.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a service and then use
    createSpeechRecognizer 
in that service. For a complete service code for this you can find the answer at [Android Speech Recognition as a service on Android 4.1 & 4.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14940657/android-speech-recognition-as-a-service-on-android-4-1-4-2/14950616#14950616)

It's a feature like this?

Comment: Thanks Smudoo, I'm not sure. I have an ongoing notification which runs in the background and I would need to add the voice recognition to that service.