# How to use Android Speech to text as Service?

Tags: android, speech-to-text

In android i am trying to develop an application where I can open messages or make a call etc. through voice. But I want my application to keep running in background, how can I convert the Google speech to text API into a service ? I will provide my work progress only if you need it, as posting it did not help me in previous questions. I have taken help from this link so far I will share my code if you want. http://www.androidhive.info/2014/07/android-speech-to-text-tutorial/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Speech Recognition as a service on Android 4.1 & 4.2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14940657/android-speech-recognition-as-a-service-on-android-4-1-4-2)

Comment: my question is different, have you visited the link I shared?