# How to open an app with voice recognition like saying "OK Google"?

Tags: java, android

I know that I can say "OK Google" and then say "open MyAppName", to open an app, but I want to directly open by just saying "Hey MyAppName". I have implemented speech recognition as in this link[Android Speech Recognition as a service on Android 4.1 & 4.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14940657/android-speech-recognition-as-a-service-on-android-4-1-4-2)
.Where do I set the keyword ? or is there any other way to do it?

Comment: This might be an OS level thing, not in your control, at least not on all devices.  One immediate problem I see is what happens if there are two apps both "listening" for the same open command.  How would the OS know which app to open?  Is it really so hard for a user to press a single icon to launch your app?